# Php removing unicode arabic characters

Tags: php, unicode, str-replace

I have a text such " مُشْكِلَةٌ " in db. How can I get " مشكلة " from this text in php( str_replace etc ). I have tried str_replace it didn't work

Comment: I don't see what exactly you want to change/replace in your string.

Comment: Show us the exact code that wasn't working. Say what you expected and what the result was.

Comment: I have no code. What I want to do is to replace characters from text and get only text consisting arabic letters. @Rizier123 please zoom screen and see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
$string = 'مُشْكِلَةٌ';
$diacritic = array('ِ', 'ُ', 'ٓ', 'ٰ', 'ْ', 'ٌ', 'ٍ', 'ً', 'ّ', 'َ');
$newString = str_replace($diacritic, '', $string);

echo "Old String : ".$string;
echo "New String : ".$newString;
```

**Output**

```
Old String : مُشْكِلَةٌ
New String : مشكلة
```

> [Demo](https://3v4l.org/fJnHs)